# Blazor Identity Accounts Registration page - how to add checkboxes?

Tags: blazor

I am a long time Xamarin dev. Doing some personal development and learning Blazor (WASM and Server).
I am using Individual Accounts and the default pages that are generated. On the registration page, I want to add two checkboxes. The code runs but the checkboxs overlaop each other and are stacked on top of the submit button.
Hoping someone will let me know what noobie mistake I have made. Thanks in advance!
Input form below:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <StatusMessage Message="@Message" />
        <EditForm Model="Input" asp-route-returnUrl="@ReturnUrl" method="post" OnValidSubmit="RegisterUser" FormName="register">
            <DataAnnotationsValidator />
            <h2>Create a new account.</h2>
            <hr />
            <ValidationSummary class="text-danger" role="alert" />
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <InputText @bind-Value="Input.Email" class="form-control" autocomplete="username" aria-required="true" placeholder="name@example.com" />
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <ValidationMessage For="() => Input.Email" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <InputText type="password" @bind-Value="Input.Password" class="form-control" autocomplete="new-password" aria-required="true" placeholder="password" />
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <ValidationMessage For="() => Input.Password" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <InputText type="password" @bind-Value="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" autocomplete="new-password" aria-required="true" placeholder="password" />
                <label for="confirm-password">Confirm Password</label>
                <ValidationMessage For="() => Input.ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating mb-2">
                <label><InputCheckbox id="jobposter" class="form-control" aria-required="true" @bind-Value="Input.IsPoster" />Job Poster</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating mb-2">
                <label><InputCheckbox id="worker" class="form-control" aria-required="true" @bind-Value="Input.IsWorker" />Worker</label>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary">Register</button>
        </EditForm>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
        <section>
            <h3>Use another service to register.</h3>
            <hr />
            <ExternalLoginPicker />
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think instead of "form-control" "form-check-input" https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/checks-radios/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your using bootstrap for css.

```html
<div class="form-check form-check-inline mb-2">
    <InputCheckbox id="jobposter" class="form-check-input" aria-required="true" @bind-Value="Input.IsPoster" />
    <label class="form-check-label" for="jobposter">Job Poster</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline mb-2">
    <InputCheckbox id="worker" class="form-check-input" aria-required="true" @bind-Value="Input.IsWorker" />
    <label class="form-check-label" for="worker">Worker</label>
</div>
```